# How to handle token characters in a dynamic RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok, let's say I have a list of prefixes that I'd want to use in a `RegExp`, that would look something like this:

```js
const prefixes = ["*","|","^"];
const prefixDetector = new RegExp(`^${prefixes.join('|')}`, 'gmi');
```

That's great and all, but the only issue is that my `RegExp` comes out like this:

```js
const regex = /^*|||^/gmi
//What Went Wrong: "|||" will search for blank characters, A.K.A "".
```

It should come out like this.

```js
const regex = /^\*|\||\^/gmi
//Expected
```

I could use code that looks like this:

```js
...
const prefixDetector = new RegExp(`^\\${prefixes.join('|\\')}`, 'gmi');
```

Assuming it'll come out as the code above, but when I add prefixes like this:

```js
const prefixes = ['*','|','^','b','s'];
```

I would get something like this:

```js
const regex = /^\*|\||\^|\b|\s/gmi
//What Went Wrong: It is correct, but "\b" and "\s" are Regex tokens in Javascript.
```

Remember, `\b` and `\s` is for word boundaries and whitespace characters.

What I'm trying to get here is to match prefixes, and the prefixes can be longer than 1 character and be customizable, so something like `/[%%]/gmi` wouldn't cut it, because that only handles 1 character.

So it would be like:

```js
const prefixes = ['%%', 'b', 'percentage', 'percent'];
const RegExp = new RegExp('...?', 'gmi');
//test RegExp on something like "%%afterprefix" or "percentthing";
```

Answer (score -2):

To prevent `Regex` from interpreting those characters with special meaning you have to escape it in your array.

E.g `["\\s", "\\b", "\\|", "\\^"]`